# Dynamically adding entries on RadioButtonList/ RadioButtonList not visible

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to add entries on a RadioButtonList dynamically (not from a database). So far I have the following code [markup and .vb] but the ListItems that are added dynamically are not shown on the screen.

When I added some ListItems at markup they showed correctly but I want to add them in a completely dynamic way as I cannot know how many entries will be needed prior to execution.

**Markup:**

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadList" runat="server" Height="42px" Width="268px">
        <asp:ListItem Text="" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**VB code:**

```
    RadList = New RadioButtonList()
If (Not IsPostBack) Then
    Dim bullet As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each bullet In question.answers
        Dim item As ListItem
        item = New ListItem("" & bullet)

        RadList.Items.Add(item)
        MsgBox("Added.." & RadList.Items(i).Text)
        i = i + 1
    Next
End If
RadList.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
RadList.Visible = True
```

I am interested as to why the entries that are added in a dynamic way are not shown on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to remove the RadList = New RadioButtonList() in your code because it is creating a new object named RadList of the RadioButtonList and ignoring your control. The code is below.

```
    If (Not IsPostBack) Then
        Dim bullet As String
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each bullet In question.answers()
            Dim item As ListItem
            item = New ListItem("" & bullet)

            RadList.Items.Add(item)
            MsgBox("Added.." & RadList.Items(i).Text)
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End If
    RadList.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    RadList.Visible = True
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Do you mind if I ask you one more thing? I have this other problem that my on_click methods only fire on the second click. On the first click the page refreshes instead of executing the on_click method. Do you have any hints? I have searched the web thoroughly but I couldn't find a solution. I will post a separate question with some code in about an hour if you'd like to check it out.